# Trying to get a complicated count of unique users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

priorities belong to users. priorities can have 4 periods (enum) - :day, :week, :month, :quarter

Im trying to write an active record .count statement that gets me the count of unique users who have a priority with the period's value equal to :day, :week, :month, :quarter.

so basically I want to know how many people have at least one priority with each of those values for periods. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Priority.group('period').count('user_id', :distinct => true)
```

Should give you a hash of periods to user counts. Grouping by period is what makes `count` return a hash rather a single value and making the count distinct ensures that users aren't double counted.

Check the explain plan but for this query to be reasonably fast you'll probably want an index on the period column (possibly a [period, user_id] index)

Comment: this actually got the count of priorities, not the count of users

Comment: This is counting the number of distinct user_ids there are for each period. If this isn't the same thing as the number of users that have a priority for each period then I've misunderstood your data model. An example of desired input/output data would help

Answer (score 0):

You need doing that in 4 requests. One by each periods.

```
User.where(:priorities => :day).count
User.where(:priorities => :week).count
User.where(:priorities => :month).count
User.where(:priorities => :quarter).count
```

Comment: this didn't work because the :day, :week, :month, :quarter values are assigned to priorities[:period], which isn't mentioned in your calls

Comment: Can you paste your model to format a good answer, because I don't understand you schema. priorities is a Hash ?